How To Deploy Node JS Project in Netlify
Currently I am having some trouble to deploy my node js application to Netlify using "Manual" manner which is using "netlify-cli".
My project folder looks like below:

All of my main code is in "index.js" like below:
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');


const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Connected to backend server!')
})

const route = require('./routes');
app.use('/income', route.incomeAPI);
app.use('/expense', route.expanseAPI);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Successfully connected to server!'));

And all of my API routes are included in "route" folder.
I have followed many tutorial and website but still failed to deploy.
Thanks and regards,
Aiman Irfan

You should have used serverless-http to deploy express app

I have tried your implementation above but I received an error below.


To deploy a Node.js project on Netlify, you need to use Netlify Functions for serverless deployment. First, move your server code to a functions directory, e.g., functions/server.js, and export the app using serverless-http. Update your package.json to include the necessary dependencies (express, serverless-http). Create a netlify.toml file with build and redirect settings:

Hi there, I want to understand, when I use Netlify Functions, do I need to change my whole code or I need to move my server code only?

When you deploy an Express app on Netlify as serverless functions, You have to wrap the express app into serverless-http module.
Let's see

Install the following dependency
npm i express serverless-http


In your base folder create app.js.
 // YOUR_BASE/app.js
 const express = require('express');
 const cors = require('cors');
 const routes = require('./routes');


 const app = express();
 const router = express.Router();

 app.use(express.json());
 app.use(cors());

 router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
     res.send('Connected to backend server!');
 });

 router.use('/income', routes.incomeAPI);
 router.use('/expense', routes.expanseAPI);

 app.use('/api',router)

 module.exports = app;


create another file in base folder called app.local.js for local development since we cannot use serverless module in local so we have app in separate module and reusing them.
 // YOUR_BASE/app.local.js
 const app = require('./app');

 app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Successfully connected to server!'));

you can use this file for development

You have to put the function folder inside the netlify folder so the path would be YOUR_BASE/netlify/function/api.js
Finally create new api.js in function folder and add this
 const serverless = require('serverless-http');
 const app = require('../../app.js');

 module.exports.handler = serverless(app);


Add the following configuration in your netlify.toml file.
 [functions];
 external_node_modules = ['express'];
 node_bundler = 'esbuild'[[redirects]];
 force = true;
 from = '/api/*';
 status = 200;
 to = '/.netlify/functions/api/:splat';


Finally manual deploy
netlify deploy



Bonus

Express Deployment Doc
Manual Deployment Doc

If you are still facing problem, try to convert CommonJS to ES Module, it would be a good practice to use ESM

Ensure that your netlify.toml file (which is Netlify's configuration file) is set up correctly to include the functions directory

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Deploy Express NodeJS App on Netlify
i) when you want to 1st create the project by connecting to your github project.
ii) create your project, push it to github.
iii) Goto your netlify dashboard, click on create new project by the
importing project. Select github branch which netlify should use to be pushing from.
iv) When you get to build files leave it as your default settings.
v) in th build type for Functions directory: functions.
vi) publish directory leave it empty.
vii) leave all other fields as default.
vii) Sample project is located on your macos netlify-host-node-demo
viii)Use the file format that way.
ix) Use the project in github repo has reference.
https://github.com/tbanj/netlify-host-node-demo
x) To view logs of the nodejs application you hosted on netlify
https://app.netlify.com/sites/projectName/logs/functions/api
Reference from
@Coding with Kazim youtube channel
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8x0Dty5D6CA
